# Why this simple Unity 3D Shader is not working in Android?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm playing with unity shader recently and I've spent 3 days try to understand why this shader works in PC/Mac but is not works for the Android platform and I'm still no clue..

Here is the shader :

```c#
Shader "Unlit/SimpleColor"
{
    Properties
    {
        [HDR] _Color("", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    }

    CGINCLUDE

    #include "UnityCG.cginc"

    StructuredBuffer<float4> _Positions;
    float4x4 _Transform;
    half4 _Color;
    float _Radius;
    float _Scale;

    float4 Vertex(float4 position : POSITION, uint id : SV_InstanceID) : POSITION
    {
        position.xyz = position.xyz * _Scale + _Positions[id].xyz * _Radius;
        return UnityObjectToClipPos(mul(_Transform, position));
    }

    half4 Fragment(float4 position : SV_POSITION) : SV_Target
    {
        return _Color;
    }

    ENDCG

    SubShader
    {
        Pass
        {
            Tags { "LightMode" = "ForwardBase" }
            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex Vertex
            #pragma fragment Fragment
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Appreciate to anyone who able to enlighten me.
Thank you.

Comment: What happens on Android? Does it not build? Is the colour wrong? Or?

Comment: `StructuredBuffer` was introduced in DirectX11. Maybe your device doesnt support that?

Comment: Doh09, the object won't shows even in Editor mode if runs in Android platform.
IanH. , I tried to find replacement for StructuredBuffer for days, from my knowledge of shader, I really need some helps. :| 


Here is the repository from Mr.Kejiro : 
https://github.com/keijiro/LightBallChain

When I switch platform to Android, the shader will not works even in Unity Editor.